# Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array. Azure function app error

Tags: azure-functions, console-application

I'm trying to load my console app solution into the Azure function app using portal directly. Solution is running as expected on my local VS2019, but same solution is loaded on function app its giving "Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array." error.
Can you suggested something, i tried to load the all required dll also using #r "./Dllname.dll", still getting the same error.

```
#r "System.Data"
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Web"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"


#r "./Microsoft.Bot.Schema.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.Graph.Beta.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.Bot.Connector.dll"
#r "./RestSharp.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#r "./Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll"
#r "./netstandard.dll"
#r "./System.Collections.dll"
// #r "./Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll"

using System;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Comment: Can you offer some code?

Comment: I have updated the question, actually even when i have removed all the code and just kept the references still its giving the error. According to me, error due to dll mismatch but not sure.

Comment: Hi, It looks like you are using C# Script. Have you already configure the assembly in `project.json` ot `function.proj`?

Comment: If you are just deploy to Azure, it should be no problem. But if you Use C# Script, please notice that it is different with VS 2019 using C# on local. Although they seems very similar.

Comment: In my azure project there is no file of name function.proj, i have function.json as below
```{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "name": "myTimer",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}```

Comment: I have not deployed it using VS2019, i'm using Azure code editor.

Comment: Yes, without `function.proj` is the key. It should be no matter with the function.json. I think the root is you use a lot of external packages but without install them.

Comment: Yes, I know. When I first use Function portal. I have face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

From your comment I know you are using Function v1. Different from Function v2, Function v1 assembly is controlled by `project.json`.

For example,

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

If you want to use custom assembly, you need to upload them first. For more information, [have a look of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies).

---

**Original Answer:**

If you are working with function v2 using C# Script, please notice that you need to use function.proj to install the package. Just like what package management works on local.

**Solution:**

***1.create an `function.proj` file***

[image]

***2.write what packages you want to install in this file.***

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" Version="1.40.3.1679" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***3.add code in .crx file:***

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static string DBConn = "123456";
public static ILogger Log = null;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    Log=log;  
    DBConn="MySQLSrvrConnectionString";
    try
    {
        string spreadsheetId = "MyGoogleSheetId";
        //SheetsService service = GetSheetService();
        //if(service!=null)
        //{
        //    DoSomethingFunc(GetInsertCommand(GetSheetVals(service,spreadsheetId)));
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.LogInformation($"Error ({DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()}): {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.LogInformation($"Function Completed at: {DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()}");
    }
    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

***4.then compilation succeeded:***

[image]

Comment: I'm not using dotnet core, rather i'm using dotnet 4.6.1, and in package references do i need to add all the references which i'm using?

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal Hi, MayureshJaiswal. Can I ask about the function version you are using now? You say you are not using dotnet core, so is it function v1? If you are using function v1, the solution wil be different.

Comment: Yes i'm using v1

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal Ok, please wait. Will update my answer.

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal I have post the Offical doc about how to do with Function v1 when using crx.

Comment: i'm having function.json and not project.json, are they same? Below is the format for function.json, it's different from what you posted.
```{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "name": "myTimer",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}```

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal I know them. They are not same. You need to create a new file, named `project.json`. `function.json` is a declarative file of function. But `project.json` is the file that manages your functions. Can this make you understand?

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal You can refer to the link I post in my update answer, it details how to do it. If you encounter other problems, please let me know. :)

Comment: It's giving below error now
``` 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue [D:\home\data\Functions\packages\nuget\System.Net.Http\4.3.4\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll]' to 'System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll]'
```
I tried to load System.Net.Http locally also

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal Are you still face the error with just keeping references?